# approximate a probability distribution by moment matching

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, method-of-moments

I have a 60-40 weighted distribution, of uniform(0,7.5) and uniform(7.5,10) respectively, i.e. 
$$f_X(x)=(0.6/7.5)1_{x∈[0,7.5)}+(0.4/2.5)1_{x∈[7.5,1]}$$

I have worked out that 
$$E(X) = 0.6(7.5/2) + 0.4((10+7.5)/2) = 5.75$$ 
$$Var(X) = 9.0208$$

Right now this distribution is continuous, and I would like to make it discrete via the method of moment matching, with number of moments p = 2 and span h = 1.25.

How do I go about this?

I sort of understand how the equations work for p=1 (matching $m_0^k$ and $m_1^k$), but I'm not sure how to work it out for p=2.

*Notes:

Method of moment matching for arithmetizing a continuous distribution

We construct an arithmetic distribution that matches p moments of the arithmetic and the true severity distributions. Consider an arbitrary interval of length $ph$, denoted by $[x_k ; x_{k+ph})$. We locate point masses $m^k_0$, $m^k_1$, $m^k_2$, ... , $m^k_p$ at points $x_k$, $x_k + h$, ... , $x_k + ph$ so that the first p moments are preserved.

The system of p + 1 equations reflecting these conditions is
$$\sum_{j=0}^p (x_k + jh)^rm^k_j = \int_{x_k - 0}^{x_k + ph - 0} x^r dF_X(x) - (*)$$

where r = 0,1,2,...,p and the notation “- 0” at the limits of the integral indicates that discrete probability at $x_k$ is to be included but discrete probability at $x_k + ph$ is to be excluded.

Arrange the intervals so that $x_k+1 = x_k + ph$ and so the endpoints coincide. Then the point masses at the endpoints are added together.

With $x_0 = 0$, the resulting discrete distribution has successive probabilities:

$f_0 = m_0^0$, $f_1 = m_1^0$, $f_2 = m_2^0$, ...

$f_p = m_p^0 + m_0^1$, $f_{p+1} = m_1^1$, $f_{p+2} = m_2^1$, ...

We need to solve the system of equations defined by $(*)$.

The solution of $(*)$ is $$m_j^k = \int_{x_k - 0}^{x_k + ph - 0} \prod_{i \neq j}\frac{x - x_k - ih}{(j-i)h}dF_X(x)$$
where j = 0,1,...,p

Comment: Could you explain what the "span" $h$ means?  (The term "span" in this sense is used nowhere in your reference.)

Comment: How do you mean "make it discrete"?

Comment: I have updated the question with all the relevant terms. Thanks for your time

Comment: Have a look at  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141652/constructing-a-continuous-distribution-to-match-m-moments