# Sampling from distribution known only by its moments

Tags: distributions, sampling, moments

Is there an efficient, numerically stable algorithm to sample from a distribution for which we know only a certain (large) number of moments?

Comment: How would that even be possible? You can't sample from an under-determined distribution. You can, of course, create distributions which e.g. have a given mean and variance, but there is no guarantee that the resulting samples would be from the distribution that you want.

Comment: This paper seems relevant: http://fks.sk/~juro/docs/paper_spie_2.pdf

Comment: What if you have 20 moments, rather than 2? 100? 1000?

Comment: Also, Wikipedia says "for the case where X has a continuous probability density function $ƒ(x), M_x(−t)$ is the two-sided Laplace transform of $ƒ(x)$", which kind of gave me hope that his Laplace transform could be inverted.

Comment: Also "if two distributions have the same moment-generating function, then they are identical at almost all points", which I took to mean that the moments contain about as much information as the original distribution - but I could be wrong here.

Comment: There exist sets of distinctly different distributions having identical moments--of all orders.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25010/identity-of-moment-generating-functions/25017#25017.

Comment: Just an idea for the univariate case, if we know up to the $n$-th moments, then we may approximate the characteristic function by Taylor expansion $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(it)^k}{k!}E[X^k],$$ given it is valid of course, then we apply Gil-Pelaez formula to recover the CDF, then do the inverse transform.

Comment: Just realized Luc Devroye's classical *Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation* has an entire section devoted to this, starting at p.682.

Comment: @whuber - there seems to be quite a good amount of subtlety here :-)

Comment: Low order moments -- even quite a few of them - don't generally pin down a distribution very well.

Comment: And high order moments - they can be so large that it's numerically very annoying :-( feels a bit hopeless.

Comment: Interesting question (and discussion)! Is there a specific application or background, or is this just curiosity on your part?

Comment: @StephanKolassa - at work, we need to classify distributions according to shape (for signal detection in security). I wanted to see how much information about a distribution's shape its moments contained, and for that I wanted to write a small program that would sample and plot a distribution given its moments. I would tell it: here are the first 10 moments, show me what the distribution looks like. Not really an application, more curiosity :-)

Comment: Hm. How about simply plotting histograms, or kernel density estimates/beanplots? If you have enough data to reliably estimate high moments, you should have enough data for such beanplots, shouldn't you?

Comment: @StephanKolassa - yes - I'm going to give up on "generating" from the moments, and simply compute the moments from different distributions we need to classify. We do have tons of data.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141652/constructing-a-continuous-distribution-to-match-m-moments?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If you have $k$ moments, one reasonable approach is to solve for the metalog distribution that has $k$ coefficients and those moments. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalog_distribution#Moments for some formulas). Then the quantile function of that distribution has a particularly simple form in terms of those coefficients, and you can use that to sample the distribution.

Comment: Doesn't this work only for $k\le 3$?  Otherwise, the moments are determined by higher-degree algebraic functions of the metalog parameters, making it difficult to find those parameters.

Comment: The moments are just polynomial in the coefficients. Let $M_k$ be the metalog function of $k$ coefficients which best matches the first $k$ moments; I’d first find $M_1$, then  use the coefficients of $M_k$ as a starting point in looking for $M_{k+1}$ (taking a big change as a sign of overfitting). This should work for $k\le 5$, the last function with tabulated moments on the metalog site (http://www.metalogdistributions.com/images/FirstTenMomentsForMetalogsUpToFiveTerms.pdf), and I’d only use sixth moments if I knew whether and why they were robust to different treatments of outliers.

Comment: "Just polynomial" is my point: solving these equations is not straightforward.  Frequently such equations have multiple solutions, too.

Comment: The straightforward approach is to use  gradient descent on the function $$\sum_j(\text{target value of }j\text{th moment }-\, j\text{th moment from coefficients})^2$$ starting at a point with zero for the highest coefficient, and the coefficients from the previous $M_k$ for the rest. This approach is not guaranteed to work (the question did not even specify that the values of the moments were all consistent!), but I think it is as likely to work as any other approach.