# Numerical method to compress empirical probability distribution

Tags: distributions, histogram, approximation, moment-generating-function, method-of-moments

I am trying to grapple with the following problem.

I have an application that develops empirical distributions.  In essence, I end up with a histogram of equally spaced $x$ values, with both a $max$ and a $min$, and the probability for each bucket.  What I need to do is 'compress' it for storage (there may be 1,000 to 10,000 buckets) so that the distribution can be recreated with reasonable accuracy.

The obvious choices are:

1. find a Taylor series approximation
2. find a Fourier transform    approximation
3. find a moment-generating approximation

Obviously with #1 one only needs convergences between the $max$ and $min$.  With #2, one would model the distribution as periodic, with one period occurring between $min(x)$ and $max(x)$.  In both cases it is obvious how to recover the distribution based on the very definition of the Taylor series and Fourier transform.

**My question is this**: if one went the route of #3, what is the 'inversion' formula that recovers a generalized functional representation of a distribution based on the first n integral moments being known?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have to compress it; with equally-spaced $x$ values, all you need to store is the overall $\min$, $\delta$, and count of number of values ($n$) - two floats and an int.  Then you need to store $n$ integers, maybe even short integers, so your total storage space is about $4n$ bytes - only 40 KB with $n=10000$, give or take a little.  This doesn't seem particularly onerous.

Comment: Consider other options.  For instance, you could fit a spline to the *actual* frequencies (not the relative frequencies) using a Poisson GLM and then normalize it.  That would likely require just a handful of coefficients and would give an easily computed formula for the log density.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141652/constructing-a-continuous-distribution-to-match-m-moments