By means of what distribution can I match the first n moments for arbitrary (i e. any) values of those moments?
Suppose I have the first n moments from some data set, either raw, centered or scaled, (or cumulants instead) whichever is more convenient for matching. Is there a continuous, continuously differentiable distribution that will allow me to match as many arbitrary values for such moments as I like? If do, what is that distribution (or are those distributions)?
If not, what distribution allows me to match the largest number of the first n moments (or cumulants)?

There are some common families that allow matching the first four moments of which the oldest is the Pearson family. There's also the Johnson $S_U$ & $S_B$ etc. Many posts on site discuss these, try a search or two. I'm not aware of widely used classes that go beyond 4th (nor would it typically be useful to try, a few moments don't pin down distributions very well). You can match more moments with discrete distributions over a suitable number of atoms (providing they're a possible combination of moments) but it seems this wouldn't suit.

See  also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141652/constructing-a-continuous-distribution-to-match-m-moments
